# A Sci-fi book about blue people who were enslaved

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I believe it was a dystopian story about blue people who had been enslaved. I remember it as a sci-fi story. I don't remember anything else about it, just that there were blue people, they were thought of as lesser beings.

Edit: I added that I think it was in the late 90's early 2000's that I read this. I believe it was new.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Please ask only one question per question: you can split this into 3 separate posts each covering one of the books you're asking about.

Comment: yep cut out book 2 and 3 and re-post those in 2 more questions :D

Comment: Unless of course you believe all three books are part of a single collection of books, in which case please edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks! I will. I found out what one of them was actually, so I can take that one out entirely.

Comment: Do you recall when you read the book and whether it was a new release at the time?

Comment: I read it when I was in my mid to late teens I believe. It was new then, but I could be wrong. I would say late 90's to early 2000's.

Comment: Blue people... Does sound like Avatar spinoff books from James C. movie.

Comment: Were the blue people subjagated by an evil wizard named Gargamel?

Comment: Haha no it wasn't the smurfs lol.

Comment: Cherubel, it was out long before Avatar.

Comment: I am searching for this too! Awesome series and I can't remember the name. There were two types of people and yes depending on the blue of their skin, one type were lesser beings. One book in the series was about the same people but they had adapted to living underwater? I would love to know if you found the name of the author

Comment: ive been looking for.this book too. i read it when i was in like the 6th grade and i cant remember the name

Answer (score 6):

If the blue people were androids, it could be John Brunner's [*Into the Slave Nebula*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8599895-into-the-slave-nebula).

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not it, but that's a close idea. I don't remember there being any androids, although it was set in the future. For some reason I'm remembering cave like holes in mountains for their homes, but I could be making that up.

Comment: Well, they were not really androids, that's just what the company that sold them said. In truth they were humans, abducted on sparsely populated frontier-worlds as children and subjected to a procedure that made their skin blue.